# Can contracts be executed on PRIVATE-NET?

Tags: contract-deployment, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Using geth commands, I've created a private blockchain network and two accounts. Using Ethereum Wallet, I've also successfully mined ether using one of the accounts. However, doing any of the following just hangs or sits idle once I kicked it off:

- Create a wallet
- Transfer ether to the second account
- Deploy a custom contract

The wallet creation just spins, as does the contract execution for the custom contract, and the transfer of ether is waiting for confirmation.

Is the reason for all this that other users need to be processing these tasks? In any case, please advise how I can resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a private blockchain with multiple accounts. Able to send ether from one account to another. I am using it by creating a web app.

Every time i transfer any ether or deploy a contract or execute any method of a contract which involves storing something on the blockchain, I unlock the main account or the account which I want to use and processing is successful.

While doing that mining should be on so that each generated transaction gets processed and required amount of gas is supplied.

Comment: I opened a geth console, unlocked my main account, then started mining. As the ether started coming in, my fund xfer and custom contract began receiving confirmations until getting all 12. The wallet is still not created. Any idea why my main account was locked in the first place?

Comment: It is expected that every transaction will require to unlock the account to perform the operation so that no one else can use your account. Thus accounts are always locked and when needed need to be unlocked. Also if the unlocked account is not used for certain time which I believe by default is 300 sec, gets auto locked again. Using the third parameter of the unlockAccount method, this duration could be changed "personal.unlockAccount(addr, password, duration)"